# Convert input double or float value into US currency format in java

Tags: java, numbers

Input: float or double amount

Output: Number or String in US currency format

Am currently using a DecimalFormater for converting float or double. The output of it is the amount in string format.

For formatting in US Currency format Am using NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(--Input Value--). But input value that accepted is only Numeric data style, not string data type.

So the input from DecimalFormater cannot be used as input to NumberFormat

Tried Using Wrapper class to convert the string to specific numeric type. But the round off to two decimal not working as excepted.

Method that Convert double value into String and double to US Format

```html
 public static string doubleInTwoDecimalPoint(double value) {
      DecimalFormat df =  new DecimalFormat("####0.00");
      String doubleInStringRep =  df.format(value);
      return doubleInStringRep;
     }

    public static void convertToUSFormat(double amount) {           
           
    System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(amount));
         }
```

Comment: Please share your current code, it's a bit hard to understand the question without it.

Comment: @Mureinik Updated with code

Comment: Do you just want the float/double to be rounded to two digits?

Comment: You probably want [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)), not NumberFormat.getInstance.

Comment: Need to round float/double to two decimal digits. But the NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance or NumberFormat.getInstance requires value to be in numeric value for format.

Comment: [Dont use `double` for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [NumberFormat::getCurrencyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)) which will format to the `Locale` you pass to it.

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(amount));
```

Example:

Input:

> 123.4567

Output:

> $123.46

Comment: Thanks. But what to do if input value (amount) is a string instead of numeric type.

Comment: If the input is a `String`, then change the line to: `System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(Double.valueOf(amount)));
`

Comment: By Using System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(Double.valueOf(amount))). Am getting error as  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Comment: @NandakumarKadavannoore I'm not sure how you're using it - but see here: https://ideone.com/PJzz19